# Glue AWS How do I create a Job on Glue AWS when I have intelligence to delete datalake and insert new records with a 14 day parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Friends,

I would like help to do a JOB on Glue AWS, where you will have an initial charge as below.

And in the next run, you will have to delete the 14 days prior to the current date, which is the 15th.

And include in the datalake the 14 days excluded by reading the legacy plus the 15th, as shown below.

Has anyone done this and can help me !!!!

```
Step 1) Initial load

Database via crawler

client table that is in the legacy

date code name

01/01/2020 001 john
01/01/2020 002 mary
01/02/2020 003 cid
01/03/2020 004 flower
01/04/2020 005 flor1
01/05/2020 006 bibi
01/06/2020 009 john k
01/07/2020 010 mary jr
01/08/2020 011 citizen
01/09/2020 012 floryyy
01/10/2020 013 florteste1
1/11/2020 014 nmnm
1/12/2020 015 lllll
01/13/2020 017 wwwww
1/14/2020 018 test

Job to data lake in Glue

tb_cadastro table
date code name

01/01/2020 001 john
01/01/2020 002 mary
01/02/2020 003 cid
01/03/2020 004 flower
01/04/2020 005 flor1
01/05/2020 006 bibi
01/06/2020 009 john k
01/07/2020 010 mary jr
01/08/2020 011 citizen
01/09/2020 012 floryyy
01/10/2020 013 florteste1
1/11/2020 014 nmnm
1/12/2020 015 lllll
01/13/2020 017 wwwww
1/14/2020 018 test
-------------------------------------------------- -------
Step 2)

On the 15th on the job processing it should look like this:

going to read the client table in the legacy database that has been changed may have changed or included as below,
you should have an intelligence where to delete the 14 days from the data lake bank and insert it back into the data lake with the new ones
records and insert the 15th which is today
 
client table that is in the legacy

date code name

01/01/2020 001 john111
01/01/2020 002 mary111
01/02/2020 003 cid111
01/03/2020 004 flor1111
01/04/2020 005 flor1
01/05/2020 006 bibittttt
01/06/2020 009 john k
01/07/2020 010 mary jr
01/08/2020 011 citizen
01/09/2020 012 floryyy
01/10/2020 013 florteste1
1/11/2020 014 nmnm
1/12/2020 015 lllll
01/13/2020 017 wwwww
1/14/2020 018 test

cargo to data lake in Glue

tb_cadastro table
date code name

01/01/2020 001 john
01/01/2020 002 mary
01/02/2020 003 cid
01/03/2020 004 flower
01/04/2020 005 flor1
01/05/2020 006 bibi
01/06/2020 009 john k
01/07/2020 010 mary jr
01/08/2020 011 citizen
01/09/2020 012 floryyy
01/10/2020 013 florteste1
1/11/2020 014 nmnm
1/12/2020 015 lllll
01/13/2020 017 wwwww
1/14/2020 018 test
01/15/2020 020 Mateus
```